# What is the minimum padding or margin between adsense content and navigation bar?

Tags: google-adsense

I am working on my website and I want to put adsense on the webpage. I am not sure how close is too close between adsense content and my navigation bar?

Comment: Are you looking for some kind of actual requirement from Google? (I don't think there is one other than avoiding confusion between ads and content.) Or for some kind of subjective evaluation?

Comment: Avoid confusion is very abstract. Almost everyone suggest put the ads color as website background color. This is definitely a confusion, isn't it?

Comment: You didn't actually answer my question. Though the point of it is that there likely isn't an answer to *yours*. Are you looking for a specific minimum distance to keep your ads away, or something? That's just not going to happen.

Answer (score 1):

There is no fixed spacing requirement other than the above mentioned "can't lead to confusion". The only notable exception to this is that AdSense placement must be a minimum of 150 pixels away from any flash games and this is to avoid accidental ad clicks from users frantically clicking around a flash game.

A good rule of thumb I have used in the past when placing AdSense ads is to use a 20 pixel margin on the sides between the content and the ad block and at least one blank line (`<p>&nbsp;</p>`) above and below. By following these rules of thumb I have never had any issues with ads being considered too close to content by Google and it has the added benefit of providing sufficient space to identify the ad block as not being part of the page content while at the same time not being such a large spacing as to waste a significant amount of screen real estate.